# ElasticSearch return conditionals

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

How do I add conditional queries to elasticsearch POST results such that I can remove certain results based on the hits array ?

Example :

If I have the following documents

> {id:1 , status:1} {id:1 , status:2} {id:2 , status:1} {id:2 ,
>   status:2} {id:2 , status:3}

I want to return the highest of each status fields :

> {id:1 , status:2}  {id:2 , status:3}

Answer (score 1):

You make an aggregation for this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "IDs": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "lastStatus": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "status": "desc"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```